# How to detect device running ios8 using xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8

I need to detect iphone 5 and iphone 6 running on the IOS8 . I am using the below code however this works only in ios7 . How do i change this to work on ios8? I have access to xcode 5 and cannot upgrade to xcode 6.

```
- (BOOL)isCurrentDeviceiPhone5{

    BOOL value = NO;


    printf("\nDetected Resolution : %d x %d\n\n",(int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,(int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector: @selector(scale)])
        {
            CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
            CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
            result = CGSizeMake(result.width * scale, result.height * scale);
            if(result.height == 960 || result.height == 480){
                value = NO;

            }else if(result.height == 1136){
                value  =YES;

            }
        }
    }else{
        printf("Device Type : iPad");
        value = NO;

    }
```

Comment: what is not working? what have you debugged? why have you over-complated checking the screen's dimension?

Comment: Also not import to know, is that Apps on the iPhone 6 and 6+ which are not build issuing the iOS 8 SDK and have the correct loading screens will report the height of an iPhone 5. Then there is the question about **WHY** do you need to detect the size?